# Adding a Root Node to Json output

Tags: python, json, parsing

I am trying to add a top-level element to a JSON output that I get from an API.

The following example shows the JSON output that I get from the API:

```
[{
    "Id": 1,
    "FirstName": "Ken",
    "LastName": "Sánchez",
    "Info": {
        "MiddleName": "J"
    }
}, {
    "Id": 2,
    "FirstName": "Terri",
    "LastName": "Duffy",
    "Info": {
        "MiddleName": "Lee"
    }
}, {
    "Id": 3,
    "FirstName": "Roberto",
    "LastName": "Tamburello"
}, {
    "Id": 4,
    "FirstName": "Rob",
    "LastName": "Walters"
}, {
    "Id": 5,
    "FirstName": "Gail",
    "LastName": "Erickson",
    "Info": {
        "Title": "Ms.",
        "MiddleName": "A"
    }
}]
```

And the following example shows the desired JSON output that contains the root element "info":

```
{
    "info": [{
        "Id": 1,
        "FirstName": "Ken",
        "LastName": "Sánchez",
        "Info": {
            "MiddleName": "J"
        }
    }, {
        "Id": 2,
        "FirstName": "Terri",
        "LastName": "Duffy",
        "Info": {
            "MiddleName": "Lee"
        }
    }, {
        "Id": 3,
        "FirstName": "Roberto",
        "LastName": "Tamburello"
    }, {
        "Id": 4,
        "FirstName": "Rob",
        "LastName": "Walters"
    }, {
        "Id": 5,
        "FirstName": "Gail",
        "LastName": "Erickson",
        "Info": {
            "Title": "Ms.",
            "MiddleName": "A"
        }
    }]
}
```

I tried to append it, however, this is included as another element at the end of each array.

Could someone give me a hint on this?

I also tried with the following code, but breaks the json format

```
    with open(file_name, 'w') as f:
        data2= '{"info":'+str(data)+'}]'
        json.dump(data2, f)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Is confusing why you use `data` as the name of the file, and the data itself.

Asuming data is already a dictionary returned by the api, you can do:

```
    with open(file_name, 'w') as f:
        json.dump({'info': data}, f)
```

Comment: Hi, that was a typo when writing the question. I've just updated the code. Thanks a lot! This should work.